# iOS App Crash: Thread 9: Fatal error: UnsafeBufferPointer has a nil start and nonzero count

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

App is crashing at following line

`cid = "CID: \(String(describing: Singleton.shared.settings.userName ?? "NA"))"`

Crashing Code:

```
static func clientIdFor(basicToken: String) -> String {
        var cid: String = ""
        if let encodedData = Data(base64Encoded: basicToken, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            let encodedString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
            if encodedString.contains(":") {
                cid = encodedString.components(separatedBy: ":").first ?? "NA"
            } else {
                cid = "CID: \(String(describing: Singleton.shared.settings.userName ?? "NA"))"  /// <- CRASH
            }
        }
        return cid
    }
```

Here is backtrace

```
 bt
* thread #9, queue = 'com.apple.root.background-qos', stop reason = Fatal error: UnsafeBufferPointer has a nil start and nonzero count
    frame #0: 0x00007fff30a08770 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report
    frame #1: 0x00007fff30a87579 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile + 201
    frame #2: 0x00007fff30740c13 libswiftCore.dylib`closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () in Swift._assertionFailure(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.StaticString, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 387
    frame #3: 0x00007fff3074097c libswiftCore.dylib`closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () in Swift._assertionFailure(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.StaticString, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 300
    frame #4: 0x00007fff30740655 libswiftCore.dylib`closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () in Swift._assertionFailure(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.StaticString, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 117
    frame #5: 0x00007fff307402aa libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._assertionFailure(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.StaticString, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 314
    frame #6: 0x00007fff3074053c libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._fatalErrorMessage(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.StaticString, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 44
    frame #7: 0x00007fff309a431d libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Dead> of generic specialization <Swift.UInt8> of Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer.init(rebasing: Swift.Slice<Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<τ_0_0>>) -> Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<τ_0_0> + 109
    frame #8: 0x00007fff308ad674 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._StringGuts.append(Swift._StringGutsSlice) -> () + 500
    frame #9: 0x00007fff3084fc0a libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Character.write<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: Swift.TextOutputStream>(to: inout τ_0_0) -> () + 26
    frame #10: 0x00007fff30735d28 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.DefaultStringInterpolation.appendInterpolation<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: Swift.CustomStringConvertible, τ_0_0: Swift.TextOutputStreamable>(τ_0_0) -> () + 40
  * frame #11: 0x00000001051e9e45 MY_APP`static UtilityManager.clientIdFor(basicToken="MY_BASIC_TOKEN==", self=MY_APP.UtilityManager) at UtilityManager.swift:213:36
```

If I do a `po` in console, the same line of code works!

```
po "CID: \(String(describing: Singleton.shared.settings.userName ?? "NA"))"
"CID: NA" /// <- Here it works and prints NA in console.
```

I guess by this point in time singleton is not initialized which is why the userName is `nil`

Any idea on why the app is crashing?

Comment: You seem to calling that from a background thread, could it be a thread issue?

Comment: @Larme, This code does not deal with the UI components, so I believe the thread on which this code runs does not matter.

Comment: Thread issue is not only about main thread & UI. It can be a thread B writing a value, and a thread C reading at the "same" time that value. Where do you set the value? It's just a suspicion.